# how to set equal top and bottom of image in android?

Tags: android

i want to set equal top and bottom of each images,how can i set for all images in android?
anybody know please give the code for that

Thanks all

Comment: I can't understand what you need. Try to rephrase you question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to set image's top and bottom in same size for android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653431/how-to-set-images-top-and-bottom-in-same-size-for-android)

Comment: @how please send code for me thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just set `android:scaleType="center"` to your ImageView for ImageBitmap, or set `android:layout_gravity="center"` to your ImageView for its layout in his parents.

it perfectly work