# how to set image's top and bottom in same size for android?

Tags: android, imageview

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I want to  display image in center and top and bottom in same size refer bellow screens,anybody know please give the code to me...
Thanks All

Comment: @i want to display image in center of the screen and image's top and bottom same size,for example image's black part ie top and bottom same height and width,please refer last image in my screen shot,i want to display image in image view like screen shot,how can i set image for this...

Answer (score 0):

Use

`android:scaleType="centerInside"`

or

`ImageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE)`

Comment: Do you layout the ImageView with fill_parent on both width and height ?